# 'runtimeerror: cuda out of memory' does not get solve

Tags: pytorch, runtime-error, gpu

I am trying to train model from [Gitub](https://stackoverflow.com), I face this error.

```
runtimeerror: cuda out of memory. tried to allocate 86.00 mib (gpu 0; 4.00 gib total capacity; 3.09 gib already allocated; 0 bytes free; 3.42 gib reserved in total by pytorch)
```

I tried to lower the *training epoch* and used some code for cleaning cache but still same issue such as

```
gc.collect()
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

I am using Nvidia Geforce GTX 1650 with

- cuda 10.2
- pytorch 1.7.0
- python 3.6
- os windows 10

Answer (score 0):

'runtimeerror: cuda out of memory' occurs when your tensors/model do not fit on the GPU device you are using. A general solution is **lowering the batch size** during training.

To help fix the issue you should supply some more information, such as:

- The model you are using.
- The tensors you are loading.
- The training code.